# I'm on vacation in Europe. Can I transfer between my 2 US bank accounts?

Tags: banking, online-banking

I'm in Europe for 5 months. I have an ATM card linked to 2 accounts at my local US bank (first account is in Euro and the second in USD).

Can I use my ATM card in Europe and transfer bfrom  my Euro account to my USD account?

Comment: This is a question which only your bank can answer. But *if* you can technically reach your online banking and *if* they allow you access from Europe, why shouldn't you be able to do this?

Comment: Thank you for your help gl, but the problem is that my bank couldn't help with that matter. locally there is no problem doing that. but i hope someone can guide me which bank or any solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Jessica if your bank can’t answer that question it is time to switch banks. But if you are already in Europe can’t you just try it out?